# java script button click not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-controls

```js
         var s ={
         rows: 10,
         cols: 10,
         width: 40,
         height: 40,
         
         
         };
 
   document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 49: case 50: case 51: case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57:
            alert('number');
            break;
        case 75:
            alert('k');
            break;
        case 79:
            alert('o');
            break;
        case 85:
            alert('u');
            break;
  case 65:
            alert('a');
            break;
  case 68:
            alert('d');
            break;
  case 87:
            alert('w');
            break;
  case 88:
            alert('x');
            break;
    }
};
   
         
         var c;
         
         
         window.onload = function(){
         var canvas = document.getElementById("gCanvas");
         c = canvas.getContext("2d");
         
         init();
         } 
         
         
         
         
         var mX;
         var mY;
         var clickedX;
         var clickedY;
         
         window.onclick = function(e){
         
         
   
   c.strokeStyle = "black";
    
   
         
         c.fillRect(Math.floor(e.offsetX/40)*40, 
                            Math.floor(e.offsetY/40)*40,
                            40, 40);
         
         mX = e.pageX;
         mY = e.pageY;
         
         if(Math.floor(mX/s.width) < s.cols && Math.floor(mY/s.height) < s.rows){
         clickedX = Math.floor(mX/s.width);
         clickedY = Math.floor(mY/s.height);
        
         console.log(clickedX + "," + clickedY);
   
   
         }
         
         }
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
         var box;
         
         box = new Image();
         box.src = "box.png";
         
         
         function init(){
         
         
         drawCanvas();
         
         }
         
         function drawCanvas(){
         
         c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
         
         for(var i=0; i<s.rows; i++){
         for(var n=0; n<s.cols; n++){
         var x = n*s.width;
         var y = i*s.height;
         c.drawImage(box, x, y);
         }
         }
         }
         
         function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "game started";
         }
   
   function test() {
             alert('game ended');
         }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.active{
    background:#357EBD;
    color:#FFF
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <body>
      <h1>grid game</h1>
   
   
   </body>
   
      
      <style>
         body{
         margin:0;
         }
         h1 {
         text-align: center;
         }
      </style>






   <body>
      <div id = "controls">
      </div>
      <div id ="gameCanvas">
         <canvas id ="gCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
      <body>
   
         <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Start game</button>
         <p id="demo"></p>
         <input type="button" value="Refresh game" onClick="window.location.reload()">
   
   <button class="button" onclick="test()">end game</button>
   </body>
   </body>
```

I'm trying to make a grid game which will allow the user to move around a grid and collect items. I've only made the grid, being able to fill in the grid when clicking a square and a few buttons but I'm facing an issue already.

When ever I click a button like restart game for example it registers a square in the top left to be filled in.

You may need to download this picture for the grid to show but the error still demonstrates itself without it. 
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>grid game</h1>


   </body>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
      <style>
         body{
         margin:0;
         }
         h1 {
         text-align: center;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         var s ={
         rows: 10,
         cols: 10,
         width: 40,
         height: 40,


         };

         document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 49: case 50: case 51: case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57:
            alert('number');
            break;
        case 75:
            alert('k');
            break;
        case 79:
            alert('o');
            break;
        case 85:
            alert('u');
            break;
        case 65:
            alert('a');
            break;
        case 68:
            alert('d');
            break;
        case 87:
            alert('w');
            break;
        case 88:
            alert('x');
            break;
    }
};


         var c;


         window.onload = function(){
         var canvas = document.getElementById("gCanvas");
         c = canvas.getContext("2d");

         init();
         } 




         var mX;
         var mY;
         var clickedX;
         var clickedY;

         window.onclick = function(e){



         c.strokeStyle = "black";



         c.fillRect(Math.floor(e.offsetX/40)*40, 
                            Math.floor(e.offsetY/40)*40,
                            40, 40);

         mX = e.pageX;
         mY = e.pageY;

         if(Math.floor(mX/s.width) < s.cols && Math.floor(mY/s.height) < s.rows){
         clickedX = Math.floor(mX/s.width);
         clickedY = Math.floor(mY/s.height);

         console.log(clickedX + "," + clickedY);


         }

         }









         var box;

         box = new Image();
         box.src = "box.png";


         function init(){


         drawCanvas();

         }

         function drawCanvas(){

         c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

         for(var i=0; i<s.rows; i++){
         for(var n=0; n<s.cols; n++){
         var x = n*s.width;
         var y = i*s.height;
         c.drawImage(box, x, y);
         }
         }
         }

         function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "game started";
         }

         function test() {
             alert('game ended');
         }






      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "controls">
      </div>
      <div id ="gameCanvas">
         <canvas id ="gCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
      <body>

         <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Start game</button>
         <p id="demo"></p>
         <input type="button" value="Refresh game" onClick="window.location.reload()">

         <button class="button" onclick="test()">end game</button>
   </body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor, paste the code into relevant boxes, click TIDY and save

Comment: You need to be more specific what the issue is by providing a snippet or a fiddle for the work you've done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I edited from your code, you called the `.drawImage()` method before declaring the variable `box`. You should also add an onload event to the `box` to call `init()`.

```js
var s = {
  rows: 10,
  cols: 10,
  width: 40,
  height: 40
};

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 49:
    case 50:
    case 51:
    case 52:
    case 53:
    case 54:
    case 55:
    case 56:
    case 57:
      alert('number');
      break;
    case 75:
      alert('k');
      break;
    case 79:
      alert('o');
      break;
    case 85:
      alert('u');
      break;
    case 65:
      alert('a');
      break;
    case 68:
      alert('d');
      break;
    case 87:
      alert('w');
      break;
    case 88:
      alert('x');
      break;
  }
};

var box;
box = new Image();
box.src = "https://i.imgur.com/5o1U7rv.png";
box.onload = function() {
  init();
};

var c;
var canvas = document.getElementById("gCanvas");
c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var mX;
var mY;
var clickedX;
var clickedY;

window.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log(4);
  c.strokeStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(Math.floor(e.offsetX / 40) * 40,
    Math.floor(e.offsetY / 40) * 40,
    40, 40);
  mX = e.pageX;
  mY = e.pageY;
  if (Math.floor(mX / s.width) < s.cols && Math.floor(mY / s.height) < s.rows) {
    clickedX = Math.floor(mX / s.width);
    clickedY = Math.floor(mY / s.height);
    console.log(clickedX + "," + clickedY);
  }
};

function init() {
  drawCanvas();
}

function drawCanvas() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  for (var i = 0; i < s.rows; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < s.cols; n++) {
      var x = n * s.width;
      var y = i * s.height;
      c.drawImage(box, x, y);
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(event) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "game started";
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function test(event) {
  alert('game ended');
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls"></div>
<div id="gameCanvas">
  <canvas id="gCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction(event)">Start game</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="button" value="Refresh game" onClick="window.location.reload()">

<button class="button" onclick="test(event)">end game</button>
```

Comment: This still produces the error I was facing before, if you click on the start game or end game button it will fill in the top left or the one adjacent to it. I'm trying to make it so only if you click on that tile will the colour fill in.

Comment: I fixed my code above, when you clicked on the start button, and also activated the onclick event of the `window`, so you need to add `event.stopPropagation()` to stop triggering the next events.